# Facebook OpenGraph API Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use a standard object type (article) with a custom action (discuss).  According to the docs, this seems possible, but I'm getting a strange error that doesn't make sense.  The error message is actually missing the reference types.  Seems like a Facebook bug, but I can't be sure.

[image: Here's my basic action config]

[image: This is the bizarre error I get]

[image: This shows that the article being referenced is valid and complete]

Any help or suggestions are most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try the code generated by Facebook (see http://i.imm.io/1ilGp.png)? It was very helpful to us just to publish the sample data (you just need to put your access token into their line). Also, maybe making the Article parameter optional will work around this issue.

Everything seems OK to me (including the Article parameter). However I never used the Graph API explorer to test the opengraph publishes (I always use curl or browser), so maybe its just the Graph API explorer error.

Comment: This also generates an error (I'll try it shortly and post the response).

Comment: curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/me/dvidshub:discuss" -F "access_token=<token>" -F "article=http://www.dvidshub.net/image/1006918/koolendong"

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Only one of  reference objects can be specified for type dvidshub:discuss.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Tried article as a required and non-required param.  Result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom action, select the advanced settings and select 'Allow Multiple' under 'Unique action'. This should fix your issue